# Excel - Macro - Data from Web - How do you make extract value equal to cell value?

Tags: excel, web, import, vba

I am sorry if I did not make my request clear enough, but I am trying to get my Excel macro to behave.

The problem is this: I want to be able to tag a particular web address and link to it on Excel. The difference is, I want to be able to CHANGE that tag by changing cell values.

The website I am interested in retrieves data the same way (table format) no matter what parameters you give it. So I would like to be able to give it a particular string (comprised of different components) and have it retrieve what I need.

I tried making a macro to do this, but it does not seem to want to copy/paste the customized address into the query box on the data input. Given that, is there any way to MAKE it grab a cell value for an address, or change the syntax of the macro to concatenate a new address?

Address:

http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=**1**&houseno=**220**&street=**west+20th+street**&go2=+GO+&requestid=0&t10=y" _

Variables in bold.

The macro script reads as such:

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=**1**&houseno=**220**&street=**west+20th+street**&go2=+GO+&requestid=0&t10=y" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$9"))

How do I grab these values from Excel cells and insert them into the macro?

(Eventually, I want to use these values to do several things, including creation of directories and insertion into Word files... but that is for later! :)  )

TIA... I hope....

(PS, sorry for formatting... I THOUGHT I had it right...)

Answer to first....answer (I am noob and cannot post response for 8hrs...)

->Thanks, I was trying to use the old "&" symbol in XL formatting w/o any spaces. I will try tomorrow and see if it works.

The key is to be able to enter any address (at this point I will have to use the formatting statements, "+" for spaces) and run the macro to get the info to be used later.

tyVm!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the values from the cells like this:

Just concatenate each part of the string to your cell reference using "&".

This is assuming cells A1 = **1**, A2 = **220**, and A3 = **west+20th+street**

```
Sub queryURL()

myURL = "URL;http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=" & Range("A1") & "&houseno=" & Range("A2") & "street=" & Range("A3") & "&go2=+GO+&requestid=0&t10=y"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=myURL, Destination:=Range("A9"))

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I am just tweaking the sub-fields (if that is the right term) to get the right settings (such as x1overwritecells rather than x1insertdeletecells...).

The end result is looking to be able to either manually enter data fields or have them in a list format that I will be able to construct several template report forms for easy distribution later.

This is the first part, the data entry and crunching into a "nice" format. The next will be seeing how I can use this data and export/import it directly into both XL files (easy) and Word files (NOT using mail merge, if possible).

If anyone has any suggestions on this, I would welcome them, but I am plodding on on my own, regardless.

Thanks again!